# Datatable.Select convert to another datatable or overwrite the same one

Tags: .net, ado.net

I have this code:

```
DataRow[] wingsBookingInterfaceRows =_uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface.Select("WingsYDossierID =" +refmDossierId);
```

I need the results of that to overwrite this datatable

```
_uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface
```

because I need to iterate over the .Rows collection

thanks

Comment: Why don't you just iterate over the rows returned by `Select` instead?

Comment: how can I do that, I dont want to use indexers or ["columnnames"]

Comment: You can always cast to the more specific row type if you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();            
DataTable newTable = table.Select("<SELECT QUERY>").CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate through the `DataRow[] wingsBookingInterfaceRows` already with a foreach.

Comment: yes, but the intellisense does not show me the column names, I dont want to use ["columnname"] to access some value because the original datatable was already from a typed dataset.  foreach(DataRow dr in wingsBookingInterfaceRows)
                {
                    dr.
                }